# How to make Drupal Commerce send email notification to the author of products sold?

Tags: 7, commerce, rules

I use Drupal Commerce and the rules module to send email which works OK. But it doesn't send the email to author node of product.

Here is an export of my current rule:

```
{ "commerce_checkout_order_email" : {
    "LABEL" : "Send an order notification e-mail",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "WEIGHT" : "4",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "TAGS" : [ "Commerce Checkout" ],
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "mimemail", "commerce_checkout" ],
    "ON" : { "commerce_checkout_complete" : [] },
    "DO" : [
      { "mimemail" : {
          "USING" : {
            "key" : "emailrenzo",
            "to" : "[commerce-order:mail]",
            "from_name" : "Regalalo",
            "from_mail" : "info@regalalo.pe",
            "subject" : "Pedido # [commerce-order:order-number] en [site:name]",
            "body" : "\u003Cdiv\u003E\r\n\u003Cimg src=\u0022\/http:\/\/34.214.32.99\/sites\/default\/files\/logo-regalalo.png\u0022\u0022\u003E\r\n\u003C\/div\u003E\r\n\r\nHola [commerce-order:owner]!!\r\ngracias por realizar un pedido en [site:name], su n\u00famero de pedido es # [commerce-order:order-number].\r\n\r\nSi este es su primer pedido con nosotros, pronto recibir\u00e1 otro correo electr\u00f3nico con las instrucciones para acceder a nuestro sitio con su nombre de usuario y contrase\u00f1a. Puede ver su historial de pedidos en cualquier momento ingresando a nuestro sitio web:\r\n\r\n[site:login-url]\r\n\r\nPuede consultar el estado de su pedido en:\r\n\r\n\u003Ctable cellspacing=\u00220\u0022 cellpadding=\u002210\u0022 border=\u00221\u0022\u003E\u003Ctr\u003E\u003Ctd\u003E\u003Ctable cellspacing=\u00220\u0022 cellpadding=\u002210\u0022 border=\u00221\u0022\u003E\u003Ctr\u003E\u003Ctd\u003E[commerce-order:commerce_line_items]\u003C\/td\u003E\u003C\/tr\u003E\u003C\/table\u003E\u003C\/td\u003E\u003C\/tr\u003E\u003C\/table\u003E\r\n\r\n[commerce-order:customer-url]\r\n\r\nPor favor comun\u00edquese con nosotros si tiene alguna duda.\r\n\r\n\u00a1Gracias por comprar en nuestra plataforma! Vuelve a visitarnos aqu\u00ed: Regalalo.PE\r\nSi tienes alguna pregunta acerca de tu pedido, contacta la tienda del producto que tendr\u00e1 el agrado de atenderte. \r\nPara otra consulta de asistencia env\u00edanos un correo a \u003Ca href=\u0022mailto:info@regalalo.pe\u0022\u003E info@regalalo.pe\u003C\/a\u003E\r\n",
            "language" : [ "commerce-order:state" ]
          },
          "PROVIDE" : { "send_status" : { "send_status" : "Send status" } }
        }
      },
      { "mail" : {
          "to" : [ "commerce-order:owner:mail" ],
          "subject" : "Pedido # [commerce-order:order-number] en [site:name]",
          "message" : "Hola [commerce-order:owner]!!\r\nGracias por realizar un pedido en [site:name], su n\u00famero de pedido es # [commerce-order:order-number].\r\n\r\nSi este es su primer pedido con nosotros, pronto recibir\u00e1 otro correo electr\u00f3nico con las instrucciones para acceder a nuestro sitio con su nombre de usuario y contrase\u00f1a. Puede ver su historial de pedidos en cualquier momento ingresando a nuestro sitio web:\r\n\r\n[site:login-url]\r\n\r\nPuede consultar el estado de su pedido en:\r\n\r\n[commerce-order:commerce_line_items]\r\n\r\n[commerce-order:customer-url]\r\n\r\nPor favor comun\u00edquese con nosotros si tiene alguna duda.\r\n\r\n\u00a1Gracias por comprar en nuestra plataforma! Vuelve a visitarnos aqu\u00ed: Regalalo.PE\r\nSi tienes alguna pregunta acerca de tu pedido, contacta la tienda del producto que tendr\u00e1 el agrado de atenderte. \r\nPara otra consulta de asistencia env\u00edanos un correo a \u003Ca href=\u0022mailto:info@regalalo.pe\u0022\u003E info@regalalo.pe\u003C\/a\u003E",
          "language" : [ "commerce-order:state" ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This rule works with user customer but not sellerr or authors, what´s your recommendation?

Comment: hi Pierre I share mi rule https://www.dropbox.com/s/yewp23pol32h5y0/rule.txt?dl=0 this rule works with user customer but not sellerr or authors, what´s your recommend ? greetins

Comment: ok i done below

Comment: ok, merci for taking my advice. Please check my edit of your question to fix formatting, grammar, etc. If you don't like my edit at all, just perform a rollback, ok? Next question about "doesn't work": edit your question (not extra comment!) to explain if you mean the 1st or 2nd Rules Action which "doesn't work". Also, have you tried any kind of Rules Debugging, or can you do an experiment to (temporary) add a "show message on site" to display values of relevant tokens that you are using in the existing Rules Actions? FYI: debugging is the art of taking away all possible problems ...

Comment: thanks for your answer, yes i tested many tokens in my rules but it works only by the customers but not auhotr or sellers

Comment: Please  note: I did not "answer" (yet ...), I only posted a comment. Also, your prior comment does not help "me" (or anybody) to better understand your question. You really need to try to improve (edit!) your question to "document" things like (a) the tokens you tested (b) which of the 2 rules actions is the one causing the problem ("does not work" does not mean anything for anybody reading your question). Please read my prior comment again, and try to EDIT your question to address all of them. Just trying to help, ok?

Comment: Where in your existing rule is there any kind of Rules Logic or token(s) that relate to the ***author*** and/or ***seller***? Even though I have no clue what all the Spanish (I think) in the Rules Actions means, I can not find anything about author or seller. If I'm right (there is nothing in it), then that explains  of course where your problem starts. My "guess" for now is that you need at least a Rules Loop to iterate of each of the products being sold, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short; you should loop over all commerce order line items, obtain the product owner and add it to a list. Then in a new loop, go through the created list to send all product owners a main.

First you need a rules component that checks if a provided line item contains a product field and pushes the author to a given list (enforcing uniqueness makes sure every product owner is only added once). You can import below code on the components tab:

```
{ "rules_product_on_line_item" : {
    "LABEL" : "get product owner from line item",
    "PLUGIN" : "rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
    "USES VARIABLES" : {
      "line_item" : { "label" : "Line item", "type" : "commerce_line_item" },
      "owners" : { "label" : "Product owners", "type" : "list\u003Cuser\u003E" }
    },
    "IF" : [
      { "entity_has_field" : { "entity" : [ "line-item" ], "field" : "commerce_product" } }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "list_add" : {
          "list" : [ "owners" ],
          "item" : [ "line-item:commerce-product:creator" ],
          "unique" : "1"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Now for the main rule, create a new variable of type `list of users`. This is where we will store all product owners in.

Create a loop over `commerce-order:commerce-line-items`. In this loop, use the component that was created above. This will fill the list of product owners.

Finally, loop over the list of product owners, and send each of them a mail. The complete rule would look something like this:

```
{ "rules_mail_all_product_owners" : {
    "LABEL" : "Mail all product owners on an order",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "WEIGHT" : "5",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "mimemail", "commerce_checkout" ],
    "ON" : { "commerce_checkout_complete" : [] },
    "DO" : [
      { "variable_add" : {
          "USING" : { "type" : "list\u003Cuser\u003E" },
          "PROVIDE" : { "variable_added" : { "product_owner_list" : "Product owner list" } }
        }
      },
      { "LOOP" : {
          "USING" : { "list" : [ "commerce-order:commerce-line-items" ] },
          "ITEM" : { "list_item" : "Current list item" },
          "DO" : [
            { "component_rules_product_on_line_item" : { "line_item" : [ "list-item" ], "owners" : [ "product-owner-list" ] } }
          ]
        }
      },
      { "LOOP" : {
          "USING" : { "list" : [ "product-owner-list" ] },
          "ITEM" : { "productowner" : "Current product owner" },
          "DO" : [
            { "mimemail" : {
                "key" : "mailkey",
                "to" : [ "productowner:mail" ],
                "from_mail" : [ "site:mail" ],
                "subject" : "",
                "body" : ""
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: This seems indeed the way to go to answer the question here. And even though I've not "tested" this rule+component, but by performing a code review (eyeballing only), I wonder if it doesn't contain a minor (though critical) mistake. Have you tested this rule+component, and if so did it produce the desired (expected) result?

Comment: I have a slightly modiefied version of this running in production. But I had to clean it up for here. What would you think the mistake is?

Comment: Hint: Is "owners" in your Rules Component really a "Parameter"?

Comment: Certainly. It is the list to which the item should be appended.

Comment: That I understand/agree. But how about this Hint 2: how do these items that get added in that component then end up (= get returned) in the variable "product_owner_list" in your main rule? You did define that variable in your main rule, but I wonder (have not tested it!) how the data from the rules Component are returned back to the main rule. am I learning something new about Rules Components here, or does that product_owner_list indeed (still) not contain any list items (that exactly is what I wonder about), snappie?

Comment: I provide the list to the component (in the main rule). The component then updates the list, and it is available in the main rule with updated values. Feel free to try it. It worked for me.

Comment: "***Provide***" you wrote in your last comment, that is what I was expecting. But reading the exported Rules Component, I seem to read that that Rules Component is NOT defined as ***Provided***, but instead as "***Parameter***". And to check another time, I just imported that Rules Component in my site, and indeed ... It says "Parameter", and not "Provided". Bottomline of what I wonder about: Should "owners" be defined as "Provided" or "Parameter"? Currently it is defined as "Parameter", and therefor I suspect that product_owner_list remains an empty list. Curious to hear your verdict.

Comment: I just checked this for the second time. It works the way it works. The component does not have to provide the variable because it modifies the received variable in place. (It does not provide a new variable.) After this component, the owners list in the main rule is updated. I appreciate you want to help, but it works the way it works.

Comment: Thanks @Neograph734 you are master!!!, I import the component and new rule it´s working so good, I´ll try to put this code: [commerce-order:commerce_line_items] for email author, do you have any idea how can i put style to table of products ? greetings

Comment: @renzo, I suppose you should be able to use normal HTML as part of the mime mail. I know of nothing within rules to easily change that. But you could ask a new question and link to this one to provide context. Perhaps someone els knows something.

Comment: ok I got it, one more time thanks @Neograph734 for this code

Comment: @renzo2015 You can use the check symbol left my post to mark the question as answered.

Comment: sure @Neograph734 I did